# What design considerations need to be made to accurately measure current flowing through a BLDC motor due to a 20khz PWM control?

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, pwm, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor

My early attempts to incorporate current sensing onboard a BLDC motor drive operating at 20khz involved the MAX40201FAUA differential amplifier (50V/V) IC and a 0.001ohm shunt resistor. Results were, at best marginal and at worst non-linear and useless. At low PWM dutycycle, the short ON pulses seemed to excite a particularly high response into the diff amplifier (to the tune of it thought it was seeing 20A when only 2.5Arms was flowing).

I need to redesign this section and I need it to be able to accurately (+/- 0.01A) measure from 0 - 30A on the VCC side of the upper level MOSFET switches. Could you guys point me in the direction of a time tested differential amplifier IC that seems suited to this application or even a modular solution that incorporates amplification and measurement into a single package, to be interfaced with over I2C, serial or even PWM (I have no idea if such a solution even exists in a PCB mountable package)?

Thank you

Comment: The 20A figure might not be that wrong, have you checked with an oscilloscope, probing on the shunts?

Comment: Also 0.001 ohm is a very low value, needing attention to detail in the layout. Can you share some screenshots of that section? Btw a Hall-effect current sensor IC may be more appropriate if you want low loss, have you considered that?

Comment: I did and the results were even crazier. I saw 50-80mv spikes that coincided with the PWM ON pulse. So if I really was seeing huge pulses, how is that handled from a current sense perspective? Filtration? My NI DAQ, sampling at 120ks/sec, will see small pulses, but no where near that high, more on the order of +/- 1A about the RMS value.

Comment: I have not considered hall effect, but I definitely will now. Do variants exist that can be used on the supply side or do they have to be ground biased?

Comment: 20A@12.5% duty cycle is 2.5Arms. Filtering is appropriate, with a time constant about 10x the PWM period (unless you need faster response for current control loop stability). Even then you can further filter it for instrumentation.

Comment: Show your sensing circuit.

Comment: A few points, low side sensing is fine for BLDC, the current flowing in can only be the same as the sum of the low side values. next up, I presume your after cycle by cycle current measurement, this is done by a circuit like you describe, but the ADC needs to sample when the phase your measuring is ON, equally you need to make sure your amplifier is not going into negative saturation, as part of some waveform will have a negative current draw for a small segment of the pattern. its slow to leave saturation.

Comment: Why not use a Hall effect device .

Comment: Show the schematics, you probably need an isolated current measurement or at least high side differential to measure phase current, else you need an estimator (a simulated measurement based on transistor current and switch state).